# Comparison of two numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I wonder what is greater $100^{300}$ or $300!$ ? And how to prove it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation will help.

Comment: I'd say that the larger is $300!$ because $\log n! \approx n \log n$ and so $\log 300! \approx 300 \log 300 > 300 \log 100 = \log 100^{300}$, but this is not a proof.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562538/which-is-larger-20-or-240

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n) gives this elementary estimate based on integrals:
$$
n! \ge e\left(\frac ne\right)^n
$$
Since $2<e<3$, this implies $\displaystyle n! > \left(\frac n 3\right)^n$, as required: just take $n=300$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, yes, indeed. But it does sound a bit silly to be haggling about a factor of $2$ when $300!>(3\times 10^{14})\cdot 100^{300}$. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For an exact (and conclusive) answer, I'd take base ten logarithms. The easy one is $\log (100^{300}) = 300\cdot \log 100 = 600$. The more difficult one is
$$
\log (300!) = \sum_{i = 1}^{300}\log i
$$
which [WolframAlpha](http://wolfr.am/1iPe5fE) says is about $614.5$. So $300!$ is the larger one, by 14 digits.